# Jibx : Internal error - cannot modify class from jar

Tags: jibx

I have two Projects : Project A and Project B 
Project A have a Class Items, Which also have collection of same class Items.

Class Items {

private List list;

}

I have included Project A in Project B class path . 
Now Project B contains Jibx binding Configuartion, Now When I tried to bind Class Items in binding.xml of my project B.

```
     <collection item-type="projectA.Items" field="items" usage="optional" create-type="java.util.ArrayList"/> 
</mapping>
```

this may be due to an error in your binding or classpath, or to an error in the JiBX code ***
     [bind] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error - cannot modify class from project A jar.

Comment: Its Work , When my class Items is copied in Project B.But its doesn't  work when we try to use class Items from the jar.

Answer (score 0):

JiBX has great multi-project support.

Check out documentation here for JiBX [modular support](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/modular-codegen.html).
We have a simple multi-project example here [in our github repository](https://github.com/jibx/maven-plugin/tree/master/test-suite/base-binding-test).

Good Luck!

Don Corley
JiBX Contributor

Comment: Thanks Don Corley. I would try suggestion and would let you know

Comment: Hii Don Corley, Still facing the same problem . Since my project A dont have any jibx , Only my Project B have Jibx configuration. And futher more. We get the error only when class Items contains its collection of List<Items>